# performing batch actions on model associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In an application, a country model contains many cities, and there are two methods which performs actions on all the cities.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities

  def destroy_cities
    self.cities.each do |city|
      city.destroy
    end
  end

  def update_cities(new_status)
   self.cities.each do |city|
      city.status = new_status
    end
  end
end
```

I wonder if there are easier ways to write those methods, like a non-existant `self.cities.destroy` and `self.cities.status = new_status`

On the efficiency standpoint, it would perform those SQL queries:

```
DELETE FROM cities WHERE country_id=#{country_id}
UPDATE cities SET status=#{new_status} WHERE country_id=#{country_id}
```

Instead of running multiple queries:

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE country_id=#{country_id}

DELETE FROM cities WHERE id=#{city_ids[0]}
DELETE FROM cities WHERE id=#{city_ids[1]}
DELETE FROM cities WHERE id=#{city_ids[2]}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the delete_all and update_all activerecord methods.

If you simply want to Keep the country but delete all cities you could do;

```
def destroy_cities
  self.cities.delete_all
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all

and for updating you could do;

```
def update_cities(new_status)
  self.cities.update_all(:status => new_status)
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all